# Is it possible to bind a click event to an image inside a button?

Tags: jquery, xhtml

I'm trying to get a button with an image inside it to fire an event.  Browser is FF4.

```
<button>
  <img src="/exp.jpg" />
</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('img').bind('click', function() {
  window.alert('I was clicked');
});
```

This however never triggers a click event?  Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why and what I need to read to understand this behaviour?

Many Thanks,

Si

**Update:**
Thanks everyone for the answers and comments.  This behaviour struck me as odd to begin with but now makes sense.  Cheers!

Comment: Why do you want to have the image have the click event handler and not the button itself?

Comment: Or... why do you need the `<button>`?

Comment: This was a simple test using jquery ui and i thought I'd add a little cross so the button could be 'closed'.  This is how I found this interesting problem with click events in button elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with this will work but will be browser specific, Town answered that it does work but it depends on your browser and after that the version of that browser. The basic button function is hardcoded into the browser so changing that is going to be buggy at best. I would suggest using a img and css to style the img border and background to look like a button.

Truthfully you may get it to work in one two or even three browsers but the aim of a developer is to make it as universal as possible (with exception to IE6 that is) so i would use your skills in the area of design to achieve what you want, it will save you a lot of headache.

Comment: Absolutely agree.  I found this behaviour by accident while playing with buttons.  Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works in Chrome, [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/hHBdX/).

However, all other browsers I've tried appear to do what you say.

If you're really after that effect you may have to use CSS to position the image above the button.

[Something like this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/4n95m/) should give you more cross-browser consistency.

Comment: Firefox 4 here.  Just tested in chrome and as you say works fine.  I thought it was something to do with bubbling or capture but couldn't work it out so asked for help :)

Comment: this is going to work buggy on every browser and even versions of that browser since button functions are hard coded into a browser.

Comment: @Si Griffiths: I've added a demo to show you what I mean regarding using CSS to position the image.  This works consistently in FF4, IE9 and Chrome 11.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do that. Clicking the image will cause the button to be clicked too. Why not piggy-back onto that event?

http://jsfiddle.net/Jaybles/hHBdX/2/

Comment: That fires twice in Chrome, which appears to be the only browser that does that... so far!

Comment: Right. My point is that in all browsers, listening for the button click will work, whereas the same cant be said for listening for the image to be clicked. That is why button click accomplishes the same thing and is the more reliable method.